# SSAS Dimension Design

Tags: ssas

I have a dimension `Accounts` which is connected to the Fact Table column `Account` via it's Primary Key.

All well until here. What I want to do is connect a separate table which only has a subset of the `Accounts` that the `Fact table` has and thus makes the cube process fail when I just add it to the dimension.

Example:

[image: Table Design]

The table `Subset of Accounts` **does not** contain all of the Accounts that the `Fact Table` has.

`Attribute 3` and `Account No` is basically a new hierarchy I want to create.

Which is the correct way to go about this? Should I just create a dummy `Attribute 3` and move `Attribute 3` and `Attribute 4` to the `Accounts` table? That's what I've been doing so far but I wanted to see if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new field called `AccountNo2`, and relate it to the table that contains the subset. That table must have a record whose key is for example an empty string, `Atribute3` and `Atribute 4` a text that indicates 'Not related', to relate the records of the fact table whose field `Account No` does not exist in the table of subsets.
While loading the fact table, the `Account No` field must contain an empty string for these records. This can increase the load time of the fact table during the ETL process but reduces its size.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. Thanks!